# Why does tasksel exist when there are already meta packages?

Tags: package-management, apt, tasksel

I've recently heard of [tasksel](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel), a tool that "installs multiple related packages as a co-ordinated "task" onto your system". What is the difference between using tasksel and installing meta packages via apt-get? What does it do that meta packages can't accomplish?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tasksel` is ancient, ancient history, and is there mainly for historical reasons. Better just to forget about it.

Comment: Then how come this tasksel screen pops up whenever you install ubuntu server if its now defunct?

Answer (score 5):

Tasksel can't really express complex dependencies that include version comparisons, optional dependencies, alternative packages, conflicts, etc.

To give a simple example: the tasksel task `dns-server` installs `bind9`, while a meta-package could depend on `bind9|pdns-server` (and a bunch of other DNS servers, but this is just an example), which means installing one of the 2 listed packages fulfils the dependency.

Answer (score 1):

one of the reason for using `tasksel` is that you don't need tu know the name of installed package (for example `SSH Server` vs package `openssh-server`)

Comment: Couldn't the same be said of Software Center then?

Comment: Software Center isn't available via command line, so it would be useless in server environment

Comment: Tasksel pre-dates software center by some considerable margin.