# How to install services that I didn't install at setup

Tags: 11.10, installation, server

When I installed ubuntu server v11.0, I was given a full list of services that I could install, like DNS, LAMP, Print Server, etc. I didn't choose any of them, because I wanted to get it over with the installation quickly. Is there a way to go back and choose one of these options and have it start its installation process EXACTLY as if I had chosen it with initial install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These "services" are called [package tasks](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/serverguide/C/installing-from-cd.html#install-tasks) and are really just predefined sets of packages, [like meta packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14153/why-does-tasksel-exist-when-there-are-already-meta-packages). You can manage them using the [`tasksel`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man8/tasksel.8.html) command. To list available tasks:

```
$ tasksel --list-tasks | grep server
i server    Basic Ubuntu server
i openssh-server    OpenSSH server
u dns-server    DNS server
u lamp-server   LAMP server
u mail-server   Mail server
u postgresql-server PostgreSQL database
i print-server  Print server
u samba-server  Samba file server
u tomcat-server Tomcat Java server
```

and to install them:

```
$ sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```